# How to put translation corpus into different files

Tags: python, corpus

I want to deal with a **one-line** translation corpus between Japanese and Chinese like

JST_JC_ENVI-abst-06A0281759-par1-sen1 ||| Ｃ＆Ｄ管理施設の高度化 ||| Ｃ＆Ｄ管理设施的高度化JST_JC_ENVI-abst-06A0281759-par1-sen2 ||| メーンのポートランドはＲｉｖｅｒｓｉｄｅリサイクリング施設（ＲＲＦ）を所有しているが，建設及び解体（Ｃ＆Ｄ）ごみの埋立地に立地している。 ||| 缅因州的波特兰拥有Ｒｉｖｅｒｓｉｄｅ循环使用设施（ＲＲＦ），但其却位置选定于建设及解体（Ｃ＆Ｄ）垃圾的填埋地。JST_JC_ENVI-abst-06A0281759-par1-sen3 ||| この施設はかさばる廃棄物，住民の出す葉やＣ＆Ｄごみを受け入れているが，その最近の作業状況を紹介した。 ||| 该设施接受体积大的废弃物、居民投弃的叶子或Ｃ＆Ｄ垃圾，本文介绍了该设施最近的作业情况。

The Chinese and Japanese are begin with the prefix `JST_JC_ENVI-abstXXXXXXXX` string and split by `|||` .

So my question is how to delete all the same prefix "`JST_JC_ENVI-abstXXXXXXXX`" strings and output the Chinese into `chinese.txt` by **line** ,the Japanese into `japanese.txt` by **line**？

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First，deal with the lines and split with space.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

infile=open('dev.txt','r')
outfile1 =open('dev-mid.txt','w')
lines = infile.read()
i = lines.split()
for e in i:
    outfile1.write(e+'\n')
```

then，use **WORD** to delete space and same prefix strings in **dev-mid.txt** .

At last ,

```
    import os


    infile=open('dev-mid.txt','r')
    outfile1 =open('dev-in.txt','w')
    outfile2 =open('dev-out.txt','w')

    i=1

    for line in infile.readlines():
        if i%2==1:
    ##        print(line)
            outfile1.write(line)
            i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
    ##        print(line)
            outfile2.write(line)
    infile.close()
    outfile1.close()
    outfile2.close()
```

Dealing with even and odd rows.
**dev-in.txt** is Japanese and **dev-out.txt** is Chinese:-D